# vbscript won't read file after 8Mb

Tags: vbscript

I have a file written in vbs that wont read a file after about 8MB.  I am currently using "Scripting.FileSystemObject".  When I test the code, I notice that it runs fine until line ~79500, thats when the "AtEndOfStream" just results in True.  I was looking for documentation, but it seems not to exist.

The code is supposed to show duplicate file information and put it in a separate file, which works well enough till around that line.
This is the section of code giving me the problem (it is the second reading function I have in the code):

```
Set first = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath + firstFileName)
Set secondFile = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath + secondFileName)
count = 0
countInLine = 0
Do Until secondFile.AtEndOfStream
    lineMatches = false
    lineOfSecond=secondFile.ReadLine
            If count > 79440 Then
                MsgBox("first line" & first.AtEndOfStream)
            End If
    Do Until first.AtEndOfStream
        lineOfFirst =first.ReadLine

            if lineOfSecond = lineOfFirst Then
                lineMatches = True
                Exit Do
            End If
    Loop
    If Not lineMatches Then
        writeFl.Write(count & "second" & lineOfSecond & vbCrLf) 
    End If
    count = count + 1
Loop
```

Comment: What is the size of the first file? ~ 8Mb?

Comment: @Amessihel the first file can be of any size, but is about 1Mb.  I changed the file sizes to see the effect and, if either file went beyond the threashold of the 79440 line number it wouldn't work

Comment: I just ran your code as an ASP Classic page (slightly edited to fit with it), and it does read all the lines of the second file, even after 79500 (just had to print the value of count after the global loop). Since your code doesn't rewind the first file after the reading inner loop, I wonder if it's not related to your issue.